# Unable to add array element under array using JSON

Tags: java, json

I have to generate JSON in below sample format:

```
    [
    {   "roleName" : "Parent Folder", "folderId" : "role1", "expanded" : true, 
        "children" : 
                    [                                                                                                     
                      { "roleName" : "subUser1 non-openable folder", "folderId" : "role11","fileicon" : true },
                      { "roleName" : "subUser2", "folderId" : "role12", "expanded" : true, 
            "children" : 
                       [        
                          { "roleName" : "subUser2-1", "folderId" : "role121", "expanded" : true, "children" : 
                           [
                            { "roleName" : "subUser2-1-1 folder ico", "folderId" : "role1211" },
                            { "roleName" : "subUser2-1-2 file ico", "folderId" : "role1212" , "fileicon" : true}
                           ]
                          }
                      ]
                      }
                    ]
    }
 ]
```

I have created POJO for same and was able to add array elements in, but unable to add one more array inside or below the element. Please suggest.

below are the pojo I am using.

```
public class TargetFolder
{
    private TargetChildren[] children;

    private String roleName;

    private String expanded;

    private Long folderId;

    public TargetFolder(String roleName,
            String isFolder, Long folderId, TargetChildren[] folderList) {
        super();
        this.roleName = roleName;
        this.expanded = isFolder;
        this.folderId = folderId;
        this.children = folderList;
    }



    public TargetChildren[] getChildren ()
    {
        return children;
    }

    public void setChildren (TargetChildren[] children)
    {
        this.children = children;
    }

    public String getRoleName ()
    {
        return roleName;
    }

    public void setRoleName (String roleName)
    {
        this.roleName = roleName;
    }

    public String getExpanded ()
    {
        return expanded;
    }

    public void setExpanded (String expanded)
    {
        this.expanded = expanded;
    }

    public Long getFolderId ()
    {
        return folderId;
    }

    public void setFolderId (Long folderId)
    {
        this.folderId = folderId;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [children = "+children+", roleName = "+roleName+", expanded = "+expanded+", folderId = "+folderId+"]";
    }
}

and

public class TargetChildren
{


    private String fileicon;

    private String roleName;

    private long folderId;


    public TargetChildren(String roleName, String fileicon, long folderId) {
        super();
        this.fileicon = fileicon;
        this.roleName = roleName;
        this.folderId = folderId;
    }


    public String getFileicon ()
    {
        return fileicon;
    }

    public void setFileicon (String fileicon)
    {
        this.fileicon = fileicon;
    }

    public String getRoleName ()
    {
        return roleName;
    }

    public void setRoleName (String roleName)
    {
        this.roleName = roleName;
    }

    public long getFolderId ()
    {
        return folderId;
    }

    public void setFolderId (long folderId)
    {
        this.folderId = folderId;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [fileicon = "+fileicon+", roleName = "+roleName+", folderId = "+folderId+"]";
    }
}
```

and below is the logic I am using to generate the JSON:

```
for(int i  = 0; i<folderList.size();i++)
        {
            if(folderList!=null)
            {
                subList  = (List)folderList.get(i);
                childFolders[i] = new TargetChildren((String)subList.get(0),(String)subList.get(2),(Long)subList.get(1));
                JSONArray arr =  new JSONArray();
                if(((String)subList.get(2)).equals("true"))
                {
                    arr.put(i, childFolders[i]);
                }
                System.out.println(arr.toString());
                //TargetChildren [] testArr = new TargetChildren[] { new TargetChildren("Folder", "folderName", 226886843L)};
            }
        }
        TargetFolder targetFolder = new TargetFolder(parentFoldername,isFolder,folderId, childFolders);
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(targetFolder);
        String jsonString = jsonObject.toString();
        System.out.println("JSON TO UI------ "+jsonString);
```

Comment: You have a malformed JSON. Please put the proper JSON you are trying to parse.

Comment: Your JSON is not valid. keys must be surrounded by quotes + Your array doesn't have a key - should be something like: "arr": [{...},{...}....].

Comment: Yes, I know it's not proper json, will post it for sure but my main concern here is  adding a complete array inside existing array..

Comment: @Codebender,ItayD I have added corrct JSON, please suggest.

Comment: Show us your POJO and how you are trying to add elements

Comment: @naveen,soana i have updated question with pojo.

Comment: Now you are still missing how you create the Objects from the JSON....

Comment: @soana i have updated question with the logic I am using to generate the JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most elegant and simple solution I can think of is adding a `toJSON` method to your POJOs and let it handle the serializing itself.

For the `TargetFolder`:

```
public JSONObject toJSON(){
    JSONObject out = new JSONObject();
    out.put("rolename", rolename);
    out.put("expanded", expanded);
    out.put("folderID", folderId);

    JSONArray children = new JSONArray();
    for(int i = 0; i < this.children.length; i++){
        children.push(this.children[i].toJSON());
    }
    out.put("children", children);

    return out;
}
```

Do the same for the `TargetChildren` and then you can convert it to JSON by calling:

```
myTargetFolder.toJSON();
```

This way you don't need to worry about the recursive structure of the resulting JSON.

If you add a constructor which takes a `JSONObject`, you can ensure consistent serialization and deserialization in one place.

There is also the GSON library from Google, which should achieve essentially the same, but I never used it, so I cannot say how it would work with that.

---

P.S.: You might want to create a common superclass for `TargetFolder` and `TargetChild` and use that as the datatype for the `children`-array, because from the JSON it seems like this array can contain objects with `TargetFolder`-properties ("expanded" and "children") and objects with `TargetChild`-properties ("fileicon")

Comment: I am confused. Do u want me to add toJSON() in my both POJO?
and where exactly I can call the myTargetFolder.toJSON();

Comment: Yes, add that method (with a meaningful implementation) to both POJOs. You can call that method anywhere, where you want to convert the POJO to JSON.

Comment: thanks for your effort, it worked for me but partially :)
I have added below method in my TargetChild and method given by you in TargetFolder:

 
  JSONArray children = new JSONArray();
  for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
   children.put(out.toString);

without children.put(out.toString) it throws Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
 at org.json.JSONObject.keySet(JSONObject.java:730).

and using children.put(out.toString) add some extra stuff in my JSON.

Comment: @nilFi I'm sorry, I can't understand your problem. Where exactly did you add that code?

Comment: I am adding below method in TargetChild:
public JSONObject toJSON(){
  JSONObject out = new JSONObject();
  out.put("nodeLabel", nodeLabel);
  if(type.equals("file"))
  {
   out.put("fileicon", fileicon); 
  }
  else {
   out.put("expanded", fileicon); 
  }
  out.put("nodeId", nodeId);
  
  JSONArray children = new JSONArray();
  for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
   children.put(out.toString());
  }
  out.put("children", children);
  return out;
 }
but I have to use toString() here -->children.put(out.toString());

Comment: without toString it gives error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError at org.json.JSONObject.keySet(JSONObject.java:730)

Comment: @nilFi `out` is only supposed to be a representation of `this` (`TargetChild`). From your question I see, that `TargetChild` only has the attributes `roleName`, `fileIcon` and `fileID`, so only these attributes should be in the JSONObject which is produced by the `toJSON`-method. If you put `out` into the JSONObject `out`, you create an infinite loop. It is the same as saying: `this.attribute = this`. I hope this helps.